# Discord bot responding to pings that aren't meant for the bot

Tags: discord.py

For example, I want the bot to delete a message that pings the owner of the server.
I'm pretty new to python, I. currently only have the code that makes the bot run

Comment: What if I wanted to delete a message that pings, but not the owner?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **check on each message** if the `message.author` mentions the server owner.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    
    # Check if message has mentions
        
    if message.mentions:
        
       # check if guild owner is in the mention list
        
       if message.guild.owner in message.mentions:
              
          # delete if yes
    
          await message.delete()
```

---

### Sources

- [On Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=#discord.on_message)

Comment: btw things like `if x: if y: do a` can be shortened to `if x and y: do a`

Comment: like `if message.mentions:` ?

Comment: In this case I was thinking about something like `if message.mentions and message.guild.owner in message.mentions:`

Comment: I think it's easier to understand for him with my code, but your solution would be indeed better.

Comment: yeah, this is more understandable. just saying in case you may need to use that in the future